# Спарсить данные с etherscan

Tags: php, javascript

Как мне с помощью пхп или js спарсить сколько было отправленно эфира с одного кошелька на другой?

Answer (score 0):

Все это можно сделать на php, используя  [curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php) и [phpQuery](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/phpquery)